# Merge excel sheets base on some conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple sheets in an excel file and I need to merge them in a single excel sheet but with some condition.
row should start with 4 and wherever it finds blank row it should break there for a particular sheet and index should not be there. I have tried with below code:

```
import pandas as pd
all_data = []
data = pd.ExcelFile(local_path)
sheets = data.sheet_names
for sheet in sheets:
    xl = data.parse(
    sheet,
    header=3,
    index_col=None,
    skiprows=None
     )
    all_data.append(xl)
pd.concat(all_data).to_csv(destination)
```

but it includes data after a blank row as well. please suggest.

please find sample dataframe and its concatenated dataframe
sheet1: 

**A  B C**

1 2 3

4 5 6

This should not included and before this one blank row is there
Sheet2:

**A  B C**

7 8 9

10    11 12


This should not included and before this one blank row is there

concatenated dataframe should look like below:

**A  B C**

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

10 11 12

Comment: please post some sample dataframes and its concatenated dataframe

Comment: pls edit your question with your dataframes

Answer (score 1):

As far as I undertend, the main issue is how to split on the blank line and leave only the first part of the dataframe (because concatenattion code seems to be correct).

So, if there's some excel file with a blank line, it will be readed as the:

```
      A       B       C
0   1.0     2.0     3.0
1   4.0     5.0     6.0
2   NaN     NaN     NaN
3   10.0    11.0    12.0
4   13.0    14.0    15.0
```

- blank line is converted to `NaN` (there are `floats`, not ints in the sample `dataframe`, because it contains `NaN` and type was changed to float). It is possible to split on the condition *"where is the row with all values equals to NaN"*.

Retrieve the index value of a such row:

```
nan_rows = df.index[df.isna().all(axis=1)]
nan_rows
Out:
Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
```

And the *numerical* index of a first row with such property is:

```
first_nan_row = nan_rows[0]
```

- `2` that case. Notice that it should be a numerice unique index. If there's no such thing, add it via `df = df.reset_index()` and remove it later.

As the number of the row was obtained, use it to split dataframe via `iloc`:

```
df_before_blank_line = df.iloc[:first_nan_row]
df_before_blank_line
Out:
            A           B           C
0         1.0         2.0         3.0
1         4.0         5.0         6.0
```

Full code sample:

```
import pandas as pd

all_data = []
data = pd.ExcelFile(local_path)
sheets = data.sheet_names
for sheet in sheets:
    xl = data.parse(
        sheet,
        header=2,
        index_col=None,
        skiprows=None
    )
    nan_rows = xl.index[xl.isna().all(axis=1)]
    first_nan_row = nan_rows[0]
    xl = xl.iloc[:first_nan_row]  # drop the lines after blank line here
    xl['sheet_name'] = sheet  # I recommend to add a sheet name to distinguish sheets later
    all_data.append(xl)
pd.concat(all_data).to_csv(destination)
```

The output should looks like:

```
            A           B           C sheet_name
0         1.0         2.0         3.0     Sheet1
1         4.0         5.0         6.0     Sheet1
0         1.0         2.0         3.0     Sheet2
1         4.0         5.0         6.0     Sheet2
```

The last column is optional (of course, you can remove it and also you can change `dtype` of the columns to `int` - if there's no more `NaN's`)

Hope it helps